# TFS 2010 query to conditionally show child Tasks for some Work Item Types but not others

Tags: tfs, workitem

I'm using the TFS 2010 query editor.  I am trying to write a Tree of Work Items query to show all User Stories and Bugs.

I'd like to be able to include all child Tasks related to the Bugs, but not show child Tasks of User Stories.  Is this even possible with TFS?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afaraid you cannot specify the condition on Work Item Type of parent work item for linked work items. 
Unless you have your own field in work items where you save the parent work item type of course. Then you could use this field for filtration.

Comment: Ok, that's what I suspected.  Thank you.